# How to get the href attribute value using enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I am a new to Clojure and enlive.

I have html like this

```
<SPAN CLASS="f10"><A HREF="value1" title="...." TARGET="detail">....</A></SPAN></DIV><DIV CLASS="p5"><SPAN CLASS="f10"><A HREF="value2" title="..." TARGET="detail">.....</A></SPAN>
```

I tried this

(html/select (fetch-url *base-url*) [:span.f10 [:a  (html/attr? :href)]]))

but it returns this

```
({:tag :a,
  :attrs
  {:target "detail",
   :title
   "...",
   :href
   "value1"},
  :content ("....")}
 {:tag :a,
  :attrs
  {:target "detail",
   :title
   "....",
   :href
   "value2"},
  :content
  ("....")}
```

What i want is just value1 and value 2 in the output. How can i accomplish it ?

Comment: Thanks @jmargolisvt , Changing html/attr? to html/attr= did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` returns the matched nodes, but you still need to extract their `href` attributes.  To do that, you can use `attr-values`:

```
(mapcat #(html/attr-values % :href)
      (html/select (html/html-resource "sample.html") [:span.f10 (html/attr? :href)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this little function because the Enlive `attr` functions don't return the values.  You are basically just walking the hash to get the value.

```
user=> (def data {:tag :a, :attrs {:target "detail", :title "...", :href "value1"}})
#'user/data

user=> (defn- get-attr [node attr]
       #_=>   (some-> node :attrs attr))
#'user/get-attr

user=> (get-attr data :href)
"value1"
```

Comment: Thank you @jmargolisvt, I tried this in my code (defn data []
  (html/select (fetch-url *base-url*) [:span.f10 [:a  (html/attr? :href)]]))
  
  
(defn get-attr [node attr]
       #_=>   (some-> node :attrs attr))

(defn get-api []
  (get-attr data :href))  and tried executing get-api and that returns nil. Any idea? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You have "data" defined as a function with `defn`.  You need just `def`.